# Wordpress one pager: how to structure / posts or pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, structure, singlepage

Heyho,

I'm new to wordpress and currently building a website for a client. It's a one-pager and I'm wondering how to build the backend.

Let's say it's a cat-business. And the structure is as following:

---

1. Haircutting

   - Baby Cat Haircutting
   - Long Hair Haircutting
   - Special Hair Cutting
2. Photoshooting

   - Single Studio Photos
   - Group Studio Photos
   - Owner + Cat Studio Photos
   - Outside Photos
3. Training

   - Faster Running
   - Higher Jumping
   - Better Mouse-Hunting
4. News
5. Contact

---

The categories 1—5 should form the Menu.

Every entry is (until now) a post and has several custom fields (e.g. Price, Duration, Location…) and that works fine. The Client needs to be able to edit / add / remove the single entries (e.g. "Special Hair Cutting").

How should I build it know?

**First Idea**

- Making Pages for each category, showing the single posts assigned to the
  "wordpress category"
- Make the Home-Page show all the pages

**Second Idea**

- Building everything in Posts
- Building also the categories 1—5 in Posts and figure out how to apply
  special CSS (workaround with Custom Fields?)

**What is the smarter way to go?**
Anyways I'd need further help afterwards, linking the best tutorials, as hours and hours of searching didn't help me any further.

Thanks.

*Appologies for my bad English*

Comment: I would use the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin and use the The Flexible Content Field. Your first solution would be my second choice.

Comment: I'd definitely prefer a free solution! What would be the downside of #1? I thought its not such a complicated solution I was looking for, just don't have sufficient wordpress experience / understanding!

Comment: #1 is harder to get build. Know that pages do not belong to categories. I would go for subpages (make WP read the page hierarchy).

Comment: I know that they do not belong to categories by default, but can I make them so – or **add them manually?** In the backend? I have about 15 items, so that wouldn't be a problem…
Do you mean subpages for the main categories 1–5, or for the content ("posts") itself? Thanks so far!

Comment: Would categories + subcategories form another solution?

Comment: Please check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93844/child-pages-loop. You need to loop through the pages with depth 1 and then through each of their subpages.

Comment: Another reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: Worked with the get_pages function! 
Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple one-pager by looping through the pages with depth 1 and then through each of their subpages. You can use the get_pages function for this.

Make sure to redirect the individual pages to an anchor on your one-pager/home (with a [redirect plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/)). This will prevent people from finding your individual pages through the search engine.

How get_pages works: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

How to loop through your (sub)pages: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93844/child-pages-loop‌​